# Are stack-allocated arrays in C zero'd out by default in C?

Tags: c, memory, stack-memory

When I allocate memory on the heap with `malloc()`, there might be garbage in that memory unless I use `calloc()` or `memset()` to zero it out. Is this the same situation for the stack, or can I safely assume anything I allocate on the stack won't have garbage in it? Also, does this differ on different systems or OSes?

Comment: Think of the cost of zeroing out the stack each time, all to pave over some undefined behaviour bugs.

Comment: If you want your array to be zeroed explicitly then either memset it or explicitly value-initialize it: `int arr[N] = {};`

Comment: @paddy: `int arr[N] = {};` is not legal in ISO C. You probably mean `int arr[N] = {0};`.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel thanks for the correction.. One of the small gotchas between C and C++, the latter of which I primarily use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the same situation on the stack.

Unless you explicitly initialize the values of variables to zero or some other value, variables with [automatic storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) will have [indeterminate values](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.19.2).